# KnockoutClassBindingProvider: How to perform a foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, knockout-binding-handlers

I see the basic example on github but I can't get it to work with my code. I should add that I'm using durandal.

How do I get the bindings to work? Am I doing anything wrong?

**Input.js**

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

    var ctor = function (value) {
        //Properties
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
        this.placeholder = 'Input';

        //Methods
        this.getBindings = function () {
            var bindings = {};
            bindings.Input = {
                value: this.value,
                attr: {
                    placeholder: this.placholder,
                },
            };
            bindings.Test = {
                text: this.value,
            };

           return bindings;
        };
    };


    return ctor;
});
```

**Form.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'Input'], function (ko, Input) {

    var ctor = function (inputs) {
        //Properties
        this.inputs = ko.observableArray(inputs);

        //Methods
        this.getBindings = function () {
            var bindings = {};
            bindings.Inputs = {
                foreach: this.inputs,
                Item: function (context, classes) {
                    return context.$data.getBindings();
                },
            };

            return bindings;
        };
    };


    return ctor;
});
```

**Module.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'Input', 'Form'], function (ko, Input, Form) {
    var ctor = function () { };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function () {
        var data = [
            new Input(123),
            new Input("Chris"),
            new Input(true)
        ];
        this.form = new Form(data);
    };

    ctor.prototype.binding = function () {
        var bindings = this.form.getBindings();
        ko.bindingProvider.instance.registerBindings(bindings);
    };


    return ctor;
});
```

**Module.html** This does not work.

```
<div id="Module">
    <div data-class="Inputs">
        <div>
            <input data-class="Inputs.Item.Input" />
            <span data-class="Inputs.Item.Test"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Module.html** This does work but I'm not using classBindingProvider for the foreach.

```
<div id="Module">
    <div data-class="Inputs">
        <div>
            <input data-bind="value: value, attr: { placeholder: placeholder }" />
            <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's no error message but the binding never happens. I just get 3 empty input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll post the code that works.

I changed two things. First, I added `<div data-class="Inputs.Item">` and then referenced the properties relative to that location (`Input` and `Test`). Second, I register the bindings immediately inside the `getBindings` functions, which will now turn them into `initBindings`.

**Input.js**

```
define(['knockout'], function (ko) {

    var ctor = function (value) {
        //Properties
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
        this.placeholder = 'Input';

        //Methods
        this.initBindings = function () { //FIX: getBindings => initBindings
            var bindings = {};
            bindings.Input = {
                value: this.value,
                attr: {
                    placeholder: this.placholder,
                },
            };
            bindings.Test = {
                text: this.value,
            };

            ko.bindingProvider.instance.registerBindings(bindings); //FIX: register instead of return
        };
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

**Form.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'Input'], function (ko, Input) {

    var ctor = function (inputs) {
        //Properties
        this.inputs = ko.observableArray(inputs);

        //Methods
        this.initBindings = function () { //FIX: getBindings => initBindings
            var bindings = {};
            bindings.Inputs = {
                foreach: this.inputs,
                Item: function (context, classes) {
                    context.$data.initBindings(); //FIX: Call the init.
                },
            };

            ko.bindingProvider.instance.registerBindings(bindings); //FIX: register instead of return
        };
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

**Module.js**

```
define(['knockout', 'Input', 'Form'], function (ko, Input, Form) {
    var ctor = function () { };

    ctor.prototype.activate = function () {
        var data = [
            new Input(123),
            new Input("Chris"),
            new Input(true)
        ];
        this.form = new Form(data);
    };

    ctor.prototype.binding = function () {
        this.form.initBindings(); //FIX: Call the init.
    };

    return ctor;
});
```

**Module.html**

```
<div id="Module">
    <div data-class="Inputs">
        <div data-class="Inputs.Item"> //FIX: no binding => Inputs.Item
            <input data-class="Input" /> //FIX: Inputs.Item.Input => Input
            <span data-class="Test"> //Fix: Inputs.Item.Test => Test
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```